# Can I use the Bundle module of the vector library?

Tags: haskell, vector

Simple question: can I use the API under `Data.Vector.Fusion.Bundle`? Is it considered public and stable? And if yes: is there more information available how to use it?

An example would be writing gathering operations in trees where data is stored in vectors in the leaves:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a

toBundle Empty        = B.empty
toBundle (Leaf x)     = B.singleton x
toBundle (Node x l r) = toBundle l B.++ B.singleton x B.++ toBundle r

toVector t = V.unfoldrN s (\b -> Just (B.head b, B.tail b)) b
     where b        = toBundle t
           (Just s) = B.upperBound (B.size b)
```

(There are no vectors in the leaves ... just imagine them :) )

As I wrote this I found out there is no `Bundle v a -> v a` function converting the bundle back to a vector ... am I missing something?

Comment: I think the only documentation is in the cited papers. You will likely find it difficult to find people who fully understand that part of the code, unfortunately.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the `Stream` infrastructure for the use case you are imagining? It is much older (and thus more stable) than the new `Bundle` material, and is universally well understood, as e.g. the corresponding material in `text` and `stream-fusion` will show.

Comment: To be honest I haven't looked at the `Stream` interface. The `Bundle` one was the one I found first. So from looking at it more closely the `Bundle` interface in fact *is* the `Stream` interface that was just renamed to `Bundle` in 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the function: `unstream :: Vector v a => Bundle v a -> v a` as implemented in the data.vector.generic.(new) module.
Refering to your `toVector` code example, I would rather suggest to avoid relying on the size hint given for the manually constructed stream/bundle and instead use a (possibly) more efficient method for the construction of the vector, e.g. by using the function: `generateM :: Monad m => Int -> (Int -> m a) -> m (Vector a)`.

In addition, from a pure conceptual view, I'm wondering whether `Leaf a` as it stands is basically equivalent to `Node a Empty Empty` and therefore possibly redundant? How's this: `type Leaf a = Node a Empty Empty`?

Comment: In fact, looking at the bundle type in detail, I came across this very interesting paper clarifing the meaning of "a bundle of streams": http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2500365.2500601. Certainly a good read and highly informative.